# Visualforce/Lightning Button Override Navigation

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightningnavigation

I'm still stuck in the dark ages in terms of Lightning development, so hoping someone can help me here:

I'd like to overrride the edit page of a Quote Line Item and take the user to a Visualforce page for certain products. For products that don't require a Visualforce page, I'd like to take them to the records standard edit page.

In my controller I'm doing:

```
public PageReference redirect() {
        PageReference productPage;
        if(product <> null) {
            if(product.product2.custom_page__c == 'Racking')
                productPage = Page.QuoteRackingPage;
            if(product.product2.custom_page__c == 'Shelving')
                productPage = Page.QuoteShelvingPage;
            else {              
                productPage = Page.QuoteStandardPage;                    
            }
        }
        return productPage;
}
```

On the QuoteStandardPage I've included the following, as I had seen it mentioned in other posts:

```
<apex:page >    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // hardcoding id for now
        sforce.one.editRecord('0QL1n000004gMTRGA2');
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

However the url seems to get stuck here and I get a blank screen:

https://csiproducts--partial.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/QuoteLineItem/0QL1n000004gMTRGA2/edit

I get the same result if I try an old school way in the controller :

```
ApexPages.StandardController(product).edit();
```

Is this even possible in Lightning? Do I need to do the whole thing in components rather than use VF?

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Andy